# Using Guzzle to send POST request with JSON

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

```
$client = new Client();
$url = 'api-url';

$request = $client->post($url, [
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
    'json' => ['token' => 'foo']
]);

return $request;
```

And I get back `502 Bad Gateway` and Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json

I need to make a POST request with some json. How can I do that with Guzzle in Laravel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give it a try

```
$response = $client->post('http://api.example.com', [
    'json' => [
       'key' => 'value'
     ]
]);

dd($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

Comment: @KiraArik which version of Guzzle are you using?

Comment: It should be $request in dd() not $result. and a square bracket is missing.
$request = $client->post('http://api.example.com', [
    'json' => [
       'key' => 'value'
     ]
]);
dd($request->getBody()->getContents());

Answer (score 1):

Take a look..

```
$client = new Client();

$url = 'api-url';

$headers = array('Content-Type: application/json');

$data = array('json' => array('token' => 'foo'));

$request = new Request("POST", $url, $headers, json_encode($data));

$response = $client->send($request, ['timeout' => 10]);

$data = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this solution. that is working on my end. I am using **Laravel 5.7**.

This is an easy solution of Make a **POST Request** from **PHP** With **Guzzle**

```
   function callThirdPartyPostAPI( $url,$postField  )
   {
     $client = new Client();
     $response = $client->post($url , [
        //'debug' => TRUE,
        'form_params' => $postField,
        'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        ]
     ]);
    return $body = $response->getBody();
  }
```

> For Use this method

```
    $query['schoolCode'] =$req->schoolCode;
    $query['token']=rand(19999,99999);
    $query['cid'] =$req->cid;
    $query['examId'] =$req->examId;
    $query['userId'] =$req->userId;

    $tURL = "https://www.XXXXXXXXXX/tabulation/update";

    $response = callThirdPartyPostAPI($tURL,$query);

    if(  json_decode($response,true)['status'] )
    {
        return success(["data"=>json_decode($response,true)['data']]);
    }
```

Comment: The question asks how to send a request with JSON. This example will not work.

Comment: can you share error code that you are getting?

Comment: can you share error that you are getting … because in my server it is working..

Comment: no , both methods working in my project.. i was facing same issue in my project many time. i used CURL for this .. but thank Pankaj ji...

Comment: please help me , i need some technical support please call me 9031261290